# Common type of Scala subclasses' runtime representation

Tags: scala, class, types, runtime, subclass

I want to create a function that returns the runtime representation of Scala subclasses that have the same superclass using `classOf`, e.g.

```
class C

class C0 extends C
class C1 extends C

def f(i: Int): Class[C] = {
  if (i % 2 == 0) classOf[C0]
  else classOf[C1]
}
```

However, the return values of `classOf[Cn]` give me the error *Expression of type classOf[Cn] doesn't confirm to the expected type Class[C]*, giving me the impression that inheritance information is lost in `Class[T]`.

I reckon `ClassTag`s could somehow help in retaining the ereased type, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class[A]` is invariant in `A`. Meaning that `Class[C1]` is *not* a subtype of `Class[C]` even though `C1` is a subtype of `C`.

You can rewrite the return type to an existential type `Class[_ <: C]` to indicate that you know that its type parameter will be a subtype of `C` but you don't know which one.

```scala
def f(i: Int): Class[_ <: C] = {
  if (i % 2 == 0) classOf[C0]
  else classOf[C1]
}
```

I suspect (but am not 100% sure right now) that it would make sense for `Class` to be covariant, but `Class` is defined in Java where *all* generic classes (except arrays which are special) are invariant.